# External program execution

Tags: java, eclipse

I am indebted always．

How can I do to start the external program of java, but it does not work.
In the following program, although I will work if started from the command line,but,It does not work when i run in eclipse on.
I am out error that appears is, and can not load the main class is missing or(エラー:メインクラスがみつからないかロードできません).
How will be able to run an external program in eclipse on what if?
Please kindly advise Thank you．

```
package test.jersey.resources;

public class Execute02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = "C:\\Users\\omiz12032\\workspace3\\TestJavaServlet\\src\\test\\jersey\\resources\\start.bat";
        try {
          Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filename);
          System.out.println("実行中");

          proc.waitFor();
          System.out.println("実行終了");
        } catch( Exception e ) {
          System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving? In order to run anything in Eclipse you will need to import your code and recompile. If you are importing a file as opposed to a project you may need to rebuild with the appropriate libraries.

Comment: please add the error message you get to your question.

Comment: `Could not find or load main class` if this is the error you get, please try to clean and rebuild your project. Also please check the launch configuration you use in eclipse -> `Green button in menu > Run Configuration` in Tab `Main` check that the class `test.jersey.resources.Excecute02` is there. If not click browse and select it.

Comment: Thank you for comment.Error message is ,Main class was not found or could not be loaded,is.But this message , it is the one that was translated into English error Japanese sentences.Therefore, it is not a text is displayed directly on the command line.

Comment: But I forgot to write,bat file to start, is to start multiple another program.Error message is class of programs that are launched from the bat file can not be found.

Comment: OK please add the content of your bat file or at least the part where you try to start the classes. It is most likely a problem with classpath setting.

Comment: Although we placed the class file with the program that starts by start.bat in the same directory as the start.bat,same error ended up out

Answer (score 0):

You're calling [`Runtime.exec(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) which delegates to [`Runtime.exec(String[], String[], File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)) in two steps, result in `null`s for second and third parameters.

Those are `envp` and `dir`. Inheriting `envp` (aka Environment Variables) from your Java process shouldn't be a problem. The bigger problem is `dir` which is the working directory. If the `.bat` file you're calling is not well-written (not ready for being executed outside its directory) it'll fail to resolve its dependencies when using your program's working directory. Try the following:

```
File workingDir = new File("C:\\Users\\omiz12032\\workspace3\\TestJavaServlet\\src\\test\\jersey\\resources");
// the no-array call of exec tokenizes your command which may lead to unexpected results if it contains spaces
// also you can put arguments here as well as separate array elements
String[] command = { "start.bat" }; // for example { "start.bat", "--fooBar" }
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, workingDir);
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments.Where i've tried,i get this error messag," Cannot run program "start.bat" (in directory "C:\Users\omiz12032\workspace3\TestJavaServlet\src\test\jersey\resources\start.bat"): CreateProcess error=267, ?f?B???"

Comment: Remove the `\start.bat` from the directory name.

Comment: After all i have this error message " Cannot run program "start.bat" (in directory "C:\Users\omiz12032\workspace3\TestJavaServlet\src\test\jersey\resources"): CreateProcess error=2, ?w?????t?@?"

Comment: Hmm, error=2 means "File not found." Try double-checking the path by using the command line: `cd C:\...\resources` and then `start.bat`. If that works, you could try using the full path in the command array.

Comment: It was confirmed directory from the command line, but the same error will come out.